# CMake undefined reference error on class dependency

Tags: c++, cmake, undefined-reference, openal

so I downloaded CLion a couple of days ago and I'm still getting used to working with CMake.

The problem here I think has a quite simple solution, yet I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm currently coding a sine wave sound generator for a project of mine, using OpenAL. I already included the FindOpenAl.cmake file to the cmake_modules directory and made sure I set up the CMakeLists.txt file as well as I could. But when I try to build the executable, I get an undefined reference error to an OpenAL function, alGenBuffers.

```
//SineWaveGenerator.h

#ifndef BLINDSOUND_SINEWAVEGENERATOR_H
#define BLINDSOUND_SINEWAVEGENERATOR_H

#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>

class SineWaveGenerator
{
    ALCdevice * dev;
    ALCcontext * ctx;
    ALuint buffer;

    SineWaveGenerator(ALCdevice * _dev, ALCcontext * _ctx);
    ALuint generateSineWave(double freq, double seconds, unsigned int sampleRate);
};

#endif //BLINDSOUND_SINEWAVEGENERATOR_H

//SineWaveGenerator.cpp

#include "../../include/Sound/SineWaveGenerator.h"

SineWaveGenerator::SineWaveGenerator(ALCdevice *_dev, ALCcontext *_ctx)
{
    this->dev = _dev;
    this->ctx = _ctx;

    alGenBuffers(1, &this->buffer);
}

ALuint SineWaveGenerator::generateSineWave(double freq, double seconds, unsigned int sampleRate)
{
    int buffer_size = (int)(sampleRate*seconds);
    short samples [buffer_size];
}

//CMakeLists.txt

make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(BlindSound)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp include/Sound/SineWaveGenerator.h src/Sound/SineWaveGenerator.cpp)
add_executable(BlindSound ${SOURCE_FILES})

#LIBRARIES
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

##SFML
find_package(SFML 2.3 REQUIRED system window graphics audio)
if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(BlindSound ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()

##OpenAL
find_package(OpenAL 1.0 REQUIRED)
if(OPENAL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(BlindSound ${OPENAL_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

I know I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. My best guess is that I should link the OpenAL lib directly to SineWaveGenerator.cpp, but I don't even know if that is possible or if it should be done.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

**EDIT**: I forgot to add the error report. It's added below.

```
/home/chemicalchems/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Debug --target all -- -j 4
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable BlindSound
CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/src/Sound/SineWaveGenerator.cpp.o: In function `SineWaveGenerator::SineWaveGenerator(ALCdevice_struct*, ALCcontext_struct*)':
/home/chemicalchems/ClionProjects/BlindSound/src/Sound/SineWaveGenerator.cpp:12: undefined reference to `alGenBuffers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/build.make:124: recipe for target 'BlindSound' failed
make[2]: *** [BlindSound] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**EDIT 2**: Detailed error report

```
/home/chemicalchems/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release --target BlindSound -- -j 4
/home/chemicalchems/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/home/chemicalchems/ClionProjects/BlindSound -B/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 BlindSound
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
/home/chemicalchems/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/home/chemicalchems/ClionProjects/BlindSound -B/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/home/chemicalchems/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release/CMakeFiles 3
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/all
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
cd /home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release && /home/chemicalchems/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/chemicalchems/ClionProjects/BlindSound /home/chemicalchems/ClionProjects/BlindSound /home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release /home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release /home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release/CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable BlindSound
/home/chemicalchems/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/src/Sound/SineWaveGenerator.cpp.o  -o BlindSound /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-system.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-window.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-graphics.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-audio.so 
CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/src/Sound/SineWaveGenerator.cpp.o: In function `SineWaveGenerator::SineWaveGenerator(ALCdevice_struct*, ALCcontext_struct*)':
SineWaveGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `alGenBuffers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/build.make:127: recipe for target 'BlindSound' failed
make[3]: *** [BlindSound] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:70: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/BlindSound.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chemicalchems/.CLion15/system/cmake/generated/BlindSound-175ed20c/175ed20c/Release'
Makefile:121: recipe for target 'BlindSound' failed
make: *** [BlindSound] Error 2
```

Comment: It appears to me that you are compiling in debug mode. And I suppose your library is in debug mode too?

Comment: I can't really answer as I don't know at all.

Comment: Could you open the Run Configuration (SHIFT+ALT+F10 or Run>Edit configurations...) and change `Configuration` combo from `Debug` to `Release` and test again?

Comment: add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt (just after `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`). And paste the detailed error report

Comment: Edited. I see a -DNDEBUG flag, maybe that does something we don't want?

Comment: Maybe. Are you sure you change the Run Configuration for `Target` `All targets`? Are you sure every library listed exists (libsfml-system.so libsfml-window.so libsfml-graphics.so libsfml-audio.so) and that is all the libraries you need? Is your library compiled with a C or C++ compiler?

Comment: Found the error. There exists no var named OPENAL_LIBRARIES, it's OPENAL_LIBRARY. Rechecked the CMakeLists.txt once again and found that. Thanks a lot for the help. Please go ahead and post the answer and I'll accept and upvote. Thanks a ton for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then:

1. Add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` (just after `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`). And paste the detailed error report.
2. Try to answer these questions: Are you sure you change the `Run Configuration` (`SHIFT+ALT+F10` or `Run>Edit configurations`) for `Target All targets` to `Release` mode? Are you sure every library listed in the detailed error exists and that are all the libraries you need? Is your library compiled with a C or C++ compiler?

As you said in the comments, the problem was that:

> There exists no var named OPENAL_LIBRARIES, it's OPENAL_LIBRARY